# Cannot add image to signature from http in Outlook or eM-Client

Tags: email, images, microsoft-outlook-2010

I've always added images to my email signature from my website, so it's embedded instead of sent as an attachment.

There have been no system changes but suddenly, I cannot do this.

When I insert an image, it asks for the file name, I add 
http://www.hertsgraphics.co.uk/Content/Images/Hertsgraphics-Logo-Email.png

However, in em-client I am told

> You don't have permission to open the file

In Outlook 2010, I am shown a list to convert the file type

[image]

If I choose Portable Network graphics I get an error message saying it can't convert the file.

If I try to add a local file (.png) then it succeeds. I've tried this with other .png files from my server and other websites not on my server, the same error persists.

I don't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: I suspect the message from em_client may hold the answer. It is telling you that you don't have permission. Has someone who manages that website tightened up the security on it?

Comment: In truth, putting images in email footers is a real pain for people. It bloats the email sizes and clogs up inboxes. Worse, it generally makes it look like all of your emails come with attachments and makes finding genuine attachments almost impossible.

Comment: @JulianKnight, first off, I said I tried other websites (not clearly, but updated)... second, it's a small file, I don't think  11k is considered bloat by any standard!

Comment: All I'm saying is that it is a pain to receive such emails and it makes managing emails difficult.